# Firebase list adapter not populating data from Firebase to Android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

java code

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://fireapp-353b2.firebaseio.com/Users id");

FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaselistadapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            database
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            TextView textView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(firebaselistadapter);
```

XML

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/lv"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
```

Rules

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}

JSON
{
  "Name" : "hbhbh",
  "Users id" : {
    "I ggvf" : "ffbv",
    "ffg" : "xxzzz",
    "ghar" : "fhjbv",
    "ghvf" : "ffhbft"
  }
}
```

The listview is definedin xml and it is taking entire screen but the textview is only written as temporary so that it can be set in the populate view .but still nothing is showing.

Comment: did you add `setLayoutManager` and `setHasFixedSize` on your `lv`?

Comment: No @koceeng .Can u tell how to do it?

Comment: I think its like this, `lv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))`. I usually wrote this when I use `RecyclerView`. And just in case (not required I think), add this `lv.setHasFixedSize(false)`.

Comment: did you solve your problem?